# ASP.NET Core - Possible Null Reference Return in Generic Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, repository-pattern

In ASP.NET Core-6 Entity Framework, I am using Generic Repository:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    Task<T> GetByIdAsync(object id);
}

public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    internal readonly DbSet<T> _table;

    public GenericRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _table = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(object id)
    {
        return await _table.FindAsync(id);
    }
}
```

I got this warning:

> '_table' is not null here
> Possible Null Reference Return in Generic Repository

How do I resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: Side note: Generic Repository pattern is considered a code smell nowadays: e.g. [read this](http://blog.marcinchwedczuk.pl/repository-pattern-my-way)

Comment: Not just a smell, but an ugly antipattern that breaks EF in unrecoverable ways. A DbSet is *already* a generic repository. A DbContext is *already* a high-level multi-entity Unit-of-Work. What's the point of renaming `FindAsync` to `GetByIdAsync` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is on another stack exchange site: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/433387/whats-wrong-with-returning-null

Quote

> You have enabled the nullable reference types (NRT) feature of C#. This requires you to explicitly specify when a null may be returned. So change the signature to:

```cs
public TEntity? Get(Guid id)
{
    // Returns a TEntity on find, null on a miss
    return _entities.Find(id);
}
```

> And the warning will go away.

I'm not using the feature, but expect your code should look like

```cs
public virtual async Task<T?> GetByIdAsync(object id)
{
    return await _table.FindAsync(id);
}
```

Comment: Even when I made id to be long or int, I still got the same issue

Comment: @Gbenga the issue is using the antipattern "Generic Repository" in the first place. This code is simply wrong, in a *lot* of ways. Right now, your methods are nothing more than aliases for the DbSet<T> methods, something that' simply not needed. What do you do for inserts or updates though? If you put a `SaveChanges` in `Insert`, you break DbContext's transactional behavior. Now you have to add explicit connections and transactions. And that `Insert` will perform 40 DELETEs as well, because `SaveChanges` saves all pending modifications in a single transaction.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - So what's the alternative to Generic Pattern?

Comment: @Gbenga directly using the `DbSet` in your code. `DbSet` already _is_ a repository.